# Why is my object not showing up on the BootstrapContext after being registered with the BootstrapRegistry?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the following...

```java
public class MyBootstrapInitializer implements BootstrapRegistryInitializer {
    @Override
    public void initialize(BootstrapRegistry registry) {
        log.debug("Initializing BootstrapRegistry "+registry.isRegistered(BootstrapItem.class));
        registry.register(
                BootstrapItem.class,
                context -> new BootstrapItem("Hello World")
        );
        if(!registry.isRegistered(BootstrapItem.class)) {
            log.error("BootstrapRegistry not initialized");
            throw new RuntimeException("BootstrapRegistry not initialized");
        }
        log.debug("BootstrapRegistry Initialized");
    }
}
```

And then I try to access it with the EventPostProcessor

```java
public class BootstrapPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor, Ordered {

    private final ConfigurableBootstrapContext bootstrapContext;

    public BootstrapPostProcessor(final ConfigurableBootstrapContext bootstrapContext) {
        this.bootstrapContext = bootstrapContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(
            final ConfigurableEnvironment environment,
            final SpringApplication application
    ) {
        log.error("Getting the Object");
        BootstrapItem bootstrapItem = bootstrapContext.get(BootstrapItem.class);
        log.error("Object message is: "+ bootstrapItem.getMessage());
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But when I run the context doesn't have the instanceSupplier. What am I missing?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ...BootstrapItem has not been registered

I have also confirmed that the same type of BootstrapItem the same type in both places.